# ngx-materialize DatePicker and TimePicker Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: angular, materialize

I'm looking for a component library for my Angular 6 project, I'm trying to test the ngx-materialize however I'm getting error with the DatePicker and TimePicker components, as following:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>       at RendererAdapter.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.RendererAdapter.invokeElementMethod
>   (core.js:8826)
>       at MzTimepickerDirective.push../node_modules/ngx-materialize/fesm5/ngx-materialize.js.MzTimepickerDirective.initTimepicker
>   (ngx-materialize.js:5475)
>       at MzTimepickerDirective.push../node_modules/ngx-materialize/fesm5/ngx-materialize.js.MzTimepickerDirective.ngOnInit
>   (ngx-materialize.js:5416)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9042)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10306)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10268)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10901)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10861)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ContentEditPageComponent.html:22)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10853)

Following my styles and script of my angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
  "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
  "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
  "node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css",
  "node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css",
  "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
  "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js",
  "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
]
```

Following the dependencies of package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@mdi/font": "^2.5.94",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "angular-6-social-login": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.1.6",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.8.4",
    "angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.10",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "ngx-materialize": "^6.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add your material module to your root module

Comment: Yes, following my app.module import  
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocialLoginModule,
    MzDatepickerModule,
    MzTimepickerModule,
    MzButtonModule,
    MzInputModule,
    FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(),
    FroalaViewModule.forRoot(),
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
  ],

Comment: did you find any solution?